# Weakly Initial Objects

Tags: category-theory

The problem states the following:

> Let $\mathscr{C}$ be a small category and let $\mathscr{D}$ be the full subcategory of $\mathbf{Set}^\mathscr{C}$ whose objects are those functors $F:\mathscr{C}\to\mathbf{Set}$ such that there is some $C\in\mathscr{C}$ for which $FC\neq \varnothing$ . Construct a jointly weakly initial set of objects in $\mathscr{D}$.

A jointly weakly initial set of objects is an indexed set of objects $\{C_i\mid i\in I\}\subseteq \mathscr{C}$ such that for any $D\in\mathscr{C}$, there exists some $i\in I$ and a morphism $f:C_i\to D$.

I know I have to construct a weakly initial set of objects $S=\{F_i\mid i\in I\} \subseteq \mathscr{D}$ as the following: for any functor $F\in\mathscr{D}$, there exists a functor $F_i\in S$ along with a corresponding natural transformation $\eta:F_i\Rightarrow F$. But I don't see how I can actually "construct" it based on the information I had. Any assistance is appreciated!

Comment: **Hint.** Consider those functors which are always there for you: the representable functors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall first the Yoneda lemma:

> For a locally small category $\mathscr C$ and a functor $F: \mathscr C \longrightarrow \mathbf{Set}$, the set of natural transformations $Nat(h_A, F)$ is canonically in bijection to $F(A)$ for all $A \in \mathscr C$. Here, $h_A$ is the representable functor $h_A(B) = \mathscr{C}(A, B)$. This bijection is given by $\eta \mapsto \eta(id_A)$.

Then consider the set $S = \{h_A : A \in \mathscr{C}\}$. Each $h_A \in \mathscr{D}$ as the set $h_A(A)$ contains the identity of $A$ and is hence nonempty. It is a set because $\mathscr{C}$ is small. Now for $F \in \mathscr D$ take, by assumption, some $A \in \mathscr C$ such that $F(A) \neq \emptyset$. By the Yoneda lemma, an element of this set corresponds to a natural transformation $\eta: h_A \longrightarrow F$. Thus, $S$ is a jointly weakly initial set of objects in $\mathscr{D}$.

Comment: Thank you! That's a very nice solution: I never know what to do first in such problems...

Comment: @SummerAtlas I'm glad I could help! As for finding what to do first, there is often in algebra only one possible thing that can be done, though this is often hard to find. In this case, we at some point need to find some actual functors $F_i$. But these categories are completely arbitrary, so there is no hope of writing down an explicit functor other than a representable one. I was forced by the utter lack of information to start with the only objects I knew. I hope that explains the thought process I used to start this problem.